# Flexbox columns horizontal gaps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to do a vertical layout with columns that wrap (I have a max height) but I can't center the columns horizontally without also setting a width (which I don't want to). I'm using flexbox and I thought using center on both justify-content and align-items would be enough but it isn't. I would like to have all the vertical columns centered in the parent, how could I achieve that without setting a width to the parent?

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please show what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can use `align-content: center` on flex-container. With this you define how items are distributed along cross-axis which in this case is `x` because you are using `flex-direction: column` so `y` is main-axis and `x` is cross-axis.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's it! I didn't know about align-content, I must have missed it when I read about flexbox. I was going mad, it was obvious I was missing something this easy. Thanks a lot.